# What is TokenCreator in solidity?

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I was going through following  [example](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#function-modifiers) in Solidity and came across this contract and I am confused if its a datatype like uint string as it is mentioned in comments as contract type what contract types are and why they are not recommended to create contracts

```
contract OwnedToken {
// TokenCreator is a contract type that is defined below.
// It is fine to reference it as long as it is not used
// to create a new contract.
TokenCreator creator;
address owner;
bytes32 name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special meaning to the name "TokenCreator", that is simply the name of a contract in that example code. In that code you will see there are two contracts defined, `OwnedToken` and `TokenCreator`.

The usage of the code `TokenCreator creator;` is creating a variable named "creator" which is of type "TokenCreator" which is the name of a contract defined in the code.

This variable can then be used to call the methods of the instantiated TokenCreator contract.